# Mimicking MessageBox(); behaviour in a popup window

Tags: c++, winapi

How to go about mimicking ::MessageBox() behavior in a custom popup(WS_POPUP) window, where the popup window waits for user click on one of the buttons and return the result of the click ? like in a ::MessageBox() when you have MB_YESNO in uType and handle to the owner window is supplied, it returns either ID_YES or ID_NO depending on which button was clicked.

In pure win32 api and c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DialogBox() is the core winapi function.

If you want to completely spin your own then you must:

1. iterate all top-level windows on the thread with EnumThreadWindows() and disable them with EnableWindow
2. run a message loop with GetMessage + DispatchMessage
3. add an exit condition to that loop, using a variable that represents the dialog return value
4. write message handlers for the buttons, they must set that variable
5. repeat step 1, re-enabling the windows
6. destroy the dialog window
7. return the variable value

Comment: To expand on point 2.) you should probably also include [`IsDialogMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx) to enable keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 2):

When you handle button's `BN_CLICKED` notification, delivered to the owner window via `WM_COMMAND` message, a call of [`EndDialog(m_hWnd, IDYES)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ends dialog box and supplies the API with a value (`IDYES`) to return to higher level caller.

Non-modal popup windows don't have returned codes (as opposed to modal dialogs and `MessageBox` modal dialog in particular), you close them with `WM_CLOSE` and you have to elaborate some way to obtain resulting codes/values from the window, if necessary.